# Is there API to get local storage, cache, indexed db statistics for chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

I am not able to find any chrome extension APIs for getting statistics (how much storage is used, how much is free etc. for a particular domain) of local storage, session storage, indexed db etc. Is there such API?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "statistics". Clarify your requirements (preferably including an example).

Comment: Ruwanka: I don't think the storage API is for that. Xan: added info, by statistics I mean how much used, how much free etc.

Comment: And why the down votes?

Comment: The downvote (at least for me) is because it's still way underspecified. Used by whom? Free in which sense, as each domain can grab some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such extension-specific API. You can see the full list [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index).

I don't even see such data in Chrome's own interface anywhere; neither in Dev Tools nor in `chrome://quota-internals/` (which gives the *usage* data but not *limits*).